# An InputStream that can be inserted into

Tags: java, concurrency, io

Is it possible to make an `InputStream` that is identical to a base `InputStream`, except that when the base stream is blocked, bytes can be inserted into the stream by calling a method? Sketch:

```
public class HackInputStream extends InputStream {
    public HackInputStream (InputStream base) { /* stuff */ }
    public int read() throws IOException { /* stuff */ }
    public void insertByte(byte b) { /* stuff */ }
}
```

I will only be inserting bytes when the base stream is definitely blocked, so race conditions shouldn't be an issue. I tried to implement this class using one thread that read bytes greedily from the base stream into a `LinkedBlockingQueue`. `insertByte` inserted the byte directly into the queue, and `read` simply read bytes from the queue, blocking when the queue was empty.

This almost worked... but when I made a `Scanner` using `new Scanner(new HackInputStream(System.in)`, the `nextLine` method didn't work. Unfortunately, the reason I wanted this weird class in the first place was to unblock a blocked `Scanner`!

(Here's the problem I'm trying to solve, in case someone has a better solution:

My program is a "shell" that launches tasks (threads) when given commands. Some of these tasks terminate on their own, and some do not. I want to return immediately to the command prompt when the task terminates, but in case the task never terminates, I want to terminate it by entering a newline.

Currently, the main thread waits for the task to terminate, while a watchdog threads waits for a newline, terminating the task if it receives one. Right now, if the task terminates on its own, I can't enter a command without manually entering a newline. The watchdog thread is uninterruptibly blocked, and it will consume the next line of input no matter what, possibly causing the next command to go unread. I'm trying to change `System.in` so that I can feed it newlines programmatically.)

Answer (score 0):

Update: I solved my problem in a much simpler way by only calling `Scanner.nextLine()` if the task was still running.